# Electron/Angular : How to use typescript component functions/variables in main.js

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

I am new to angular , electron.

I am trying to use type script component functions/variables in main.js.

I have LicesneController component which holds emailId, I want to call some methods at the time of tool closure which required emailId(stored in loginCompoenent).

I tried several ways to achieve this :

1. Local and session storage: Not worked as they cannot be used at client side.  : giving error as localStorage is not defined
2. Include LicesneController  module in main.js  `const { LicenseController } = require('./src/lib/LicenseController');` : giving Exception as Cann't find module

> Question is :

- why #2 is not working any reason (all the paths are correct) ?
- Is there any other way to achieve this scenario ?
- If we are using node local storage , how we can hold values set in ts file and use in js file for node local storage.

Comment: This is two questions not one and is lacking a [mcve]

Comment: Also potentially opinion based. Please read the [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this scenario by using win.webContents.send and ipc renderer.

I was trying to call typescript methods from main.js

in main.js:

```
    win.webContents.send('On Close');
```

in typeScript :
app.component.ts :

```
ipcr: IpcRenderer;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.ipcr = window.ipcRenderer;
    this.ipcr.on('On Close', (event, arg) => {
      // Do Some stuff here
    });
  }
```